# Generating a random number to be used as same in subsequent pages

Tags: php

Currently I am generating a random number for my advertising landing page to make up for **MB** being used and it's working nicely.

But I am wondering if it's possible for me to somehow get the same number that is being generated each time with `<?php echo(rand(10,20)); ?>` so I can use it in multiple locations.

Comment: sure, you can use sessions.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Could you show me a Demo if you wouldn't mind?

Comment: `session_start(); $_SESSION['var'] = rand(10,20); $var = $_SESSION['var'];` that ought to work.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you so much !

Comment: You're most welcome. I wrote that from the top of my head. ;-)

Comment: you can delete the question if you want to. or, if you really want me to post an answer, I will. I'm not in this for the points. The choice is yours ;-)

Comment: I decided to post an answer below with an example for you and for future visitors to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using sessions.

First you need to start a session, assign a session array to the random function, then a variable from that session array.

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['var'] = rand(10,20); 

$var = $_SESSION['var'];
```

Then you can use that in subsequent pages, just as long as you start the session in those pages also.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Example:

File 1

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['var'] = rand(10,20); 

echo $var = $_SESSION['var'];
```

File 2

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

echo $var = $_SESSION['var'];
```

Sidenote:

Make sure there isn't anything above that, as it may trigger a headers sent notice.

If you do get one, visit the following page on Stack:

- [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)